Can not access configuration wizard after Sharepoint 2019 installation
I need help please to start Farm Configuration wizard.  I have installed Sharepoint 2019 as a single server on a client server.  The account I use to do the installation has local admin rights on the server and has db_creator and db_security roles on the Database.
After the installation, the product configuration wizard should open, but then I get 'Sorry site has not been shared with you'.  I can open the Central admin, but when I want to select a Web Application, it does not show any.  When I want to create a new web application, it is greyed out.  When I go to the Configuration Wizard, I do not get options to start the wizard - it only says Farm Configuration but no link.  (I started the IE/Edge as admin)
Please assist on how I can start using the Wizard to finish the setup?

The answer was a very simple, I had to run Central Admin on the SQL server and it worked perfectly.  I was able to run the config wizard and setup the first site.
